# How to iterate loop and return the original data value from duplicated

Tags: javascript, html, angular, loops, filter

How to iterate loop and return the original data from duplicated

I need to use it only for loop.

```
Array >
0: 2019
1: 2019
2: 2020
3: 2019
4: 2016
5: 2016
6: 2016
7: 2019
8: 2019
9: 2019
10: 2019


I need only [2019,2016,2020];
```

I don't want the duplicated values.

I hope you guys can help

Comment: You need to iterate all the array data to get the values, then, for each value, use another array to store data without duplicated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const uniqueYears = []
years.forEach(year => {
    if(!uniqueYears.includes(year)){
        uniqueYears.push(year)
    }
});
```

Demo:

```js
 const years = [
    2019,
    2019,
    2020,
    2019,
    2016,
    2016,
    2016,
    2019,
    2019,
    2019,
    2019
];


const uniqueYears = []
years.forEach(year => {
    if(!uniqueYears.includes(year)){
        uniqueYears.push(year)
    }
});

console.log(uniqueYears);
```